# How to match id key from two JSON files then update the source JSON with changes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, ecmascript-6

This is a bit complicated but I am sure a stackoverflow coding genius will grasp easily (kudos from a noob).  I have a `source.json` file, and a `changes.json` file. In the changes file, I have CRUD type directives where I update, create, delete, etc. This is for a command line tool in node I am building.

To update a playlist entry, I will have to match the `payload.id` in the changes to the playlist.id in the original file... and then I am assuming `delete.json()` the original entry and mutate the change. For clarity, I only need assistance with the update part. Not sure how to match id's across the source and changes. I am guessing .filter(), or .reduce()?

source.json:

```
"playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8",
          "32"
        ]
      }
]
```

changes.json:

```
"playlists": [{
            "action": "update",
            "payload": [{
                "id": "1",
                "owner_id": "2",
                "song_ids": [
                    "8"
                ]
            }]
        }
```

desired output write to output.json

```
"playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8"
        ]
      }
]
```

My code so far which works great, but don't know how to match the `id` from the source (playlist.id) to the change (payload.id) and if a match, delete the record from the souce and replace with my change record.  I think it will need to be just a subroutine in the `update` part of the `if` clause and then a .push().  Thanks everyone!

```
    // Stream in source file
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./' + inputFile));

    // Stream in changes file
    const changes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./' + changesFile));

    for(const [table, actions] of Object.entries(changes)) {
        console.log([table]);
        if(!(table in data))continue;
        
        // iterate through inner CRUD directives and mutate payloads
        for(const actionDetail of actions) {
            if(actionDetail.action === 'create') {
                console.log('This is a CREATE entry');
                data[table].push(...actionDetail.payload);
            }

            if(actionDetail.action === 'delete') {
                console.log('This is a DELETE entry');
            }

            if(actionDetail.action === 'update') {
                console.log('This is a UPDATE entry');
                // const something = (is (source)payload.id === (changes)playlist.id) {
                //     if so, delete source entry and push new entry
                //     data[table].push(...actionDetail.payload);
                //}
            }

        }
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

Comment: it's quite difficult to understand the format of your data. You should provide an example of a given input and what you expect as the output.

Comment: Thank Ben.  I updated the changes.json to reflect what I want to happen. Basically one of the song_ids is removed.  So, I want to compare the id in changes.json to the one in source.json, and then update the record to have the song id removed and the new file written....it's like a CRUD operation with an API, but through a command line app and json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your dataset and applying the fact that you want to mutate your initial data object, you could something like:

```
console.log('This is a UPDATE entry');
actionDetail.payload.forEach((payload) => {
  const index = data.playlists.findIndex(
    (playlist) => playlist.id === payload.id
  );
  if (index > -1) data.playlists[index] = payload;
});
```